# Bootstrap table disappeared after inserting with Ajax Form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to update my table with UpdateTargetId after adding with Ajax BeginForm. The insertion was successful but my table disappears. I guess it's related to the view returned from the controller but I don't fully understand. . I am sorry about that.
Codes I wrote:

Ajax BeginForm:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Customers", "Customer", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess="customerSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "customersTable", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customers.musteri_id, new { id = "customer_id" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customers.crud_type, new { id = "crud_type" })

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Müşteri Adı</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriAd, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerNameInput", maxlength = 25, required = "required", pattern = "[A-Za-zğüşıöçĞÜŞİÖÇ\u0020]+" })
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Müşteri Soyadı</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriSoyad, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerSurnameInput", maxlength = 20, required = "required", pattern = "[A-Za-zğüşıöçĞÜŞİÖÇ\u0020]+" })
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Telefon Numarası</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriTel, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerPhoneInput", maxLenght = 14, required = "required" })
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>
            }
</div>
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Customers()
{
        try
        {
            CustomerViewModel customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
            customerViewModel.CustomersList = customerService.GetCustomers();
            return View(customerViewModel);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
}
```

I am using 2 actions in my `CustomerController`. One is for you to see and the other is for me to insert, update and delete operations.